# Ironpython 2.7.9 ImportException: 'No Module Named errno' when importing another module in .NET application

Tags: c#, python, .net, jinja2, ironpython

I am attempting to run a simple python script within my .net application using IronPython. I have installed the nuget package into the project (I have NOT installed the ironpython cli on my machine) and have authored this code to handle setting paths, reading output, and setting input.

```
this.engine = Python.CreateEngine();
this.scope = this.engine.CreateScope();

this.streamOut = new MemoryStream();
this.streamErr = new MemoryStream();
this.engine.Runtime.IO.SetOutput(this.streamOut, Encoding.Default);
this.engine.Runtime.IO.SetErrorOutput(this.streamErr, Encoding.Default);

// this is a locally set environment variable 
string pythonRootPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PythonPath");
ICollection<string> searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
searchPaths.Add($@"{pythonRootPath}\Lib\site-packages\");
searchPaths.Add($@"{pythonRootPath}\Lib");
engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);

this.engine.Execute(@"import jinja2");
```

Executing the script results in the following exception

```
IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: 'No module named errno'
```

My C# project has references to the following relevant (to IronPython) assemblies:

- IronPython (v2.7.9)
- IronPython.Modules
- IronPython.SQLite
- IronPython.Wpf
- Microsoft.Dynamic
- Microsoft.Scripting
- Microsoft.Scripting.Metadata

My paths appear to be well enough set for my purposes as it's not the import of jinja2 itself that causes the error and I am able to import some standard library modules. However, I've seen that the `os` package fails to import for the same reason as jinja2. I also cannot import errno directly as expected, but I can import it directly if I run it via the python 2.7 cli so the package is installed.

I'm very much out of ideas here if anyone has any suggestions.